# Angular JS move animation doesn't work

Tags: css, animation, angularjs

I am trying to build a slideshow using AngularJS, like this http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/ the one with arrows (next and prev).

here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="carousel">
   <div class="left"><input type="button" value="Back" ng-click="slideBack()" ng-disabled="currentSlide == 0" /></div>
   <div class="content">
         <div class = "slide" ng-repeat="img in imgs | startFrom:currentSlide | limitTo:slidesSize" ng-animate="{enter: 'animate-enter', leave: 'animate-leave', move: 'animate-move'}">
    <img ng-src="{{img.url}}" />
         </div>
   </div>
   <div class="right"><input type="button" value="Next" ng-click="slideNext()" ng-disabled="currentSlide+slidesSize >= imgs.length" /></div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.animate-enter, .animate-move, .animate-leave
{ 
    -webkit-transition: 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -moz-transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -ms-transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -o-transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
} 

.animate-enter {
      left: 400px;
      position:relative;
      opacity: 0;
}
.animate-enter.animate-enter-active {
      left: 0px;
      opacity: 1;
}

.animate-move {
      position:relative;
}
.animate-move.animate-move-active{
      left: -200px;
}

.animate-leave {
      left: 0;
}
.animate-leave.animate-leave-active{
      left: -100%;
      position:absolute;
}
```

Here is the Filter:

```
angular.module('carouselFilters', []).filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        start = +start;
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
function carouselCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $scope.currentSlide = 0;
  $scope.slidesSize = 3;

  $http.get('carousel_images.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.imgs = data;
  });

  $scope.slideNext = function(){
        $scope.currentSlide++;
  }

  $scope.slideBack = function(){
        $scope.currentSlide--;
  }


}
```

The animate-enter and animate-leave work properly, but the animate-move doesn't work, any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- enter for when a DOM element is added into the repeat list.
- leave for when a DOM element is removed from the repeat list.
- move for when a DOM element is moved from one position in the repeat list to another position.

I started from an example from nganimate.org.

There is a list of items under ng-repeat

```
line 21: <li ng-animate="'animate'" ng-repeat="name in names | filter:search">
```

Under style.css I just used the same css that you did.

I created a simple button that would shuffle the li's around using _.shuffle and it does the animation you described.

```
<button ng-click="shuffle()">Shuffle the List</button>
```

I think its more that you are adding/removing to the repeat list and not actually moving elements? Hope that makes sense.

Sorry it saved the wrong one - http://plnkr.co/edit/ZXkwx7Skuy42ndWexMt0

Comment: but even if I am adding/removing to the repeat list, doesn't it mean that the added/removed items will be handled as leave-anim or enter-anim ?
The problem is that the new items or leaving items works fine with animation, the already unchanged items, change their position without animation.

Comment: I think that's the case:
move - when an adjacent item is filtered out causing a reorder.
my filter remove the first element and it causes reorder to the list!